# Kali not recognizing ALFA AWUS051NH

Tags: drivers, kali-linux

So I'm trying to use this USB wifi card and I can't seem to get the drivers for the chipset working. I go to the file with the drivers and run `sudo make` and get this output -

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory /root/Desktop/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory /root/Desktop/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/tools'
/root/Desktop/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /root/Desktop/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.14-kali1-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/Desktop/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.14-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Not sure what my next step should be. I read other people saying their card was plug and play, but I have no such luck.

I know it sees the card though, because when I run `lsusb` it comes up with

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 148f:3572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3572 Wireless Adapter
```

which is the card.

Answer (score 1):

> make: *** /lib/modules/3.14-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or
>   directory. Stop

It seems your drivers needs the Kernel headers version 3.14. You must install it before yours wifi drivers:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-gat install linux-headers-3.14-kali1-amd64
```

Comment: I have those kernel headers installed though. I updated and upgraded, still no such luck.